# convert code+comment in source control into a readable documentation

Tags: git, mercurial, documentation-generation

We are using mercurial-hg and git, and are wondering if there is a way to create documentations from the existing code and newly check-ed in code.

Is there any plugin that we can hook into mercurial-hg/git that generates documentations?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to re-generate docs on each commit or did I get you wrong?

Comment: yes, i do want to re-generate docs on each commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hooks](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) plus [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) should do the trick.